# i have not an apple id and password.i have iphone 5S.how unlock it without id or password

Tags: iphone, apple-id, password, restart

I have not an apple id and password.i have iPhone5s.how unlock it.

Answer (score 0):

You can signup a Apple Id for free here:
[Create a Apple Id](https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create)

And if you have the invoice of the iPhone 5S, You can go to the Apple Store offline to get help.